# Android Keypad Disturbs View

Tags: android, authentication, android-animation

I tried creating login page like facebook, but the keypad is disturbing the editview position and other widgets in the UI.

How to design like facebook login page, with animation and positioning the widget in the center.

Once the keypad is visible, all the widget should adjust in the screen. I need guidance. Please help me.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Set android:windowSoftInputMode attribute to adjustResize in your AndroidManifest.xml.   And then make sure your layout will show a centered view in both sizes.